# Upgrading to Angular 8 from 7 Broke Script debugging in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, angular8

After Upgrading to Angular 8, Script Debugging in VS 2017 (not VS Code) seems to be broken with break points not being hit for Chrome and Edge and limited with IE

On Chrome and Edge the Breakpoints do not get hit with the error 'Break point is not bound'
With IE it works But I cannot see the variable values in Watch

I has Updated the TSC version to 3.4.1 for VS 2017 just in case.
Finally I downgraded to Angular 7 (Used the previous package.json and ran npm install) the debugging is back and working fine.

Setting the breakpoints in Chrome development mode works, but what I see there is the compile version of the code not my typescript code

I believe this could because the map files are not found by VS2017. IS there a way around this.. An Config change perhaps